# What is the correct damage for a Dragonclaw's Scimitar?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, published-adventures, roll20, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen

I purchased the roll20 version of Hoard of the Dragon Queen a while ago. It includes all the monsters needed for the campaign. The roll20 version of the Dragonclaw has two attacks included:

- Scimitar: +5 to hit, 1d6 slashing damage
- Scimitar (Fanatical Advantage): +5 to hit, 3d6 slashing damage

I have been playing using these attacks for a while but I recently noticed that the [D&D Beyond Dragonclaw](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/dragonclaw) actually has the Scimitar damage listed as (emphasis mine):

> Scimitar. Melee Weapon Attack: +5 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: **6 (1d6 + 3)** slashing damage.

I searched for [HotDQ errata](https://media.dnd.wizards.com/HotDQ-Errata.pdf) and this is not listed. I am leaning towards the D&D Beyond version being correct with the Scimitar being a finesse weapon and using DEX bonus for damage.

I don't own a physical copy of the book. What is the correct damage for a Dragonclaw's Scimitar attack?

Comment: Just to clarify, is this question based on the fact that the roll20 version (judging by your bullet points, which I assume come directly from the roll20 version) do not include the DEX modifier in the damage?

Comment: @NathanS Yes, I want to confirm if the roll20 version is incorrect or that was something that is actually done in the book

Comment: Out of interest, do the other stat blocks provided in roll20 also omit the STR/DEX/whatever modifiers from damage?

Comment: @NathanS Yes, any modifier is usually included in damage rolls automatically by roll20 in provided published content

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The book matches D&D Beyond

In the *Hoard of the Dragon Queen*, p. 89, the stats of the Dragonclaw shows the Scimitar attack as:

> ***Scimitar.*** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +5 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. *Hit:* 6 (1d6 + 3) slashing damage.

In other words, it matches [D&D Beyond's statblock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/dragonclaw).

It is likely that the roll20 version forgot to add their DEX modifier (which is listed as +3 in their statblock in the *HotDQ* book), since (as you said in a comment; it might be deleted for future readers of this answer) roll20 does usually include such modifiers in the damage for such attacks.